# Caps lock on and off reversed Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: keyboard, 14.10, capslock

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 on a laptop, and after I close the lid (meaning, logging out), when I open the lead again the Caps Lock mode is reversed: when it's supposed to be on it's off and when it's supposed to be off it's on.
What do I do about it? It only happens after I open the lid of the laptop, but I'm pretty sure it has to do with the settings.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but after waking from sleep on a PC. Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

On the icon that says "En", which has the language and Character map,

Select "Text Entry Settings" and see what options are set up for your computer to solve this issue.

Mine had "Switch to Next source using" and "Switch to previous source using"; this for the input setting... I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Did not encounter this bug in 18.04, 20.04 but in 22.04 it is back again!

Answer (score 1):

Though I found this bug on Fedora, the symptoms were the same as described here.
As a workaround I rebooted my laptop and this resolved the issue.
Also there is a relevant [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/267999).

Answer (score 1):

The Bug is closed but I see this issue still happening even on the latest distro.

It's fixable without a reboot.

You can toggle the keyboard leds directly from within
*/sys/class/leds/* by setting a value of 1 or 0 to enable disable a led for a specific device.

or simply:

Turn **on** caps lock light for all connected keyboards

```
echo 1 | sudo tee `ls /sys/class/leds/*capslock/brightness`
```

Turn **off** caps lock for all connected keyboards

```
echo 0 | sudo tee `ls /sys/class/leds/*capslock/brightness`
```